# Japanese in VF generated pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I need to render Japanese characters as HTML in a pdf that's generated using Visualforce page. I want all the formatting to be applied along with the Japanese characters.

I have used 'Arial Unicode MS' font as suggested in SF documentation which seems to work on plain text but not on HTML.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" standardController="EmailMessage" renderAs="pdf">

<head>
    <style>
       body {
            font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS', 'Courier', 'Helvetica', 'Times-Roman';
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <apex:outputText value="{!EmailMessage.TextBody}" /> <br/><br/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!EmailMessage.HtmlBody}" escape="false"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the text you are trying to render? Maybe the error is with your HTML in the second output text. To be clear, this `<apex:outputText value="おはよう！"/>` works just fine.

Comment: Looks like escape=true is adding font-family='nobile,sans-serif' to every HTML tag inside the outputText. Is there a native way to remove that font-family?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I still see it rendering all the characters, with or without `escape`. Maybe there's some CSS in the `HtmlBody` parameter. Did you check that?